# Visual Studio 2013 Express Templates Not Showing

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm currently trying to setup [cosmos](http://cosmos.codeplex.com) on Visual Studio 2013 Express. I've installed 3 templates and they're not showing up in File > New Project... I was wondering if anyone knows what the problem(s) are/is. I restarted my computer twice and that doesn't seem to be the fix.

Comment: What folder did you place the templates in? In my VS 2013 Express, I have a folder Templates with subfolders ItemTemplates and ProjectTemplates.

Comment: I used an installer, from cosmos. The link is in the question. I've checked the template folders and cosmos looks like it was installed properly.

Comment: VS is looking for the templates in folders specified in menu Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General > that shows editable paths for those default directories. I believe that is where File > New Project gets its templates.

Comment: Yes, it was installed in the correct directory I believe. It's just that VS is not seeming to show up when I click New Project... If you would like to help me further/use teamviewer to see you can add me on skype: miguel.renaud1  TeamViewer - id: 537 943 538 password: pontus